# Setting multiple pages to the same app cache manifest file causes same description to show up for all

Tags: kik

I set the manifest file for multiple pages on my website sandboxd.com to point to the same manifest file. Before doing this there were 4 entries listed on the Kik optimized search each with appropriate titles/thumbnails/descriptions. After setting these 4 different pages (3 games + 1 main site), all the titles/thumbnails/descriptions changed to the main page's. Even though they still point to different web addresses.

I've since set each page endpoint to have a different manifest file, but the entries already listed on Kik optimized results still all show the same info. You can see what I'm talking about by searching "sandboxd" on Kik. You should see 4 seemingly identical results each pointing to different addresses.

Is there something I should be doing to fix this? There was nothing in the documentation about using the same manifest for multiple pages, so I assumed this was okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your websites have the same title and description in their HTML. For example check the source of these urls:

https://www.sandboxd.com/

https://www.sandboxd.com/games/5

https://www.sandboxd.com/games/10

Comment: Ah thanks I was looking at the live DOM. JavaScript was updating it immediately on load.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I believe you can do dynamic assignment for that stuff as long as it happens before the kik.js script runs.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think the data is collected from the Kik robot which I doubt is executing JS.